# IPython on Zsh Terminal

Tags: python, terminal, ipython, zsh

Ever since I installed oh-my-zsh and iTerm2 emulator for my terminal I can't seem to access ipython any longer from my terminal. Would be great if any of you can help out!

$ ipython
zsh: command not found: ipython

Thxx,
J

Answer (score 1):

[Configure your PATH](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/zsh#Configuring_.24PATH) to include the directory containing the ipython executable. Assuming `ipython` "worked" under `/bin/sh`, you could find the path to the executable using

```
% sh -c "which ipython"
```